# Prove, by the definition of continuity, that $f(x)=ax^n$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I would really appreciate an extra pair of eyes or two to see if I missed any details here.

Proof. We will break the proof into a quadotomy.

i) Suppose $n=1$, then $\forall \ \varepsilon>0$, and $\forall \ x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, pick $\delta = \varepsilon/|a|$ so that $|x-x_0|<\delta$ implies
$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|ax-ax_0|=|a||x-x_0|<|a|\delta=|a|\varepsilon/|a|=\varepsilon.$$
So, $f$ is continuous for $n=1$, and we can assume $n\geq 2$.

ii) Suppose $n\geq 2$ and $x_0=0$, then $\forall \ \varepsilon>0$, pick $\delta=\sqrt[n]{\varepsilon/|a|}$ so that $|x-0|<\delta$ implies
$$|f(x)-f(0)|=|ax^n-a0^n|=|a|\cdot|x|^n<|a|\delta^n=|a|(\sqrt[n]{\varepsilon/|a|})^n=\varepsilon.$$
So, $f$ is continuous for $n\geq 2$ and $x_0=0$ we can assume $|x_0|>0$.

iii) Suppose $n\geq 2$ and $x_0>0$, then $\forall \ \varepsilon>0$, pick $\delta=\min\{\varepsilon/(K\cdot|a|),x_0/2\}$, where $K=x_0^{n-1} \frac{1-(3/2)^n}{1-3/2}$, so that $|x-x_0|<\delta$ implies
$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|ax^n-ax_0^n|=|a|\cdot|x-x_0|\cdot |x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}x_0+\cdots+xx_0^{n-2}+x_0^{n-1}|$$
since $|x-x_0|<x_0/2$, we know $x_0/2<x<3x_0/2$, then
$$<|a|\cdot|x-x_0|\cdot[(3x_0/2)^{n-1}+x_0(3x_0/2)^{n-2}+\cdots+x_0^{n-2}(3x_0/2)+x_0^{n-1}]$$
$$=|a|\cdot|x-x_0|\cdot x_0^{n-1}[(3/2)^{n-1}+(3/2)^{n-2}+\cdots+3/2+0]$$
$$=|a|\cdot|x-x_0|\cdot x_0^{n-1}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^j=|a|\cdot|x-x_0|\cdot x_0^{n-1}\frac{1-(3/2)^n}{1-3/2}=K\cdot|a|\cdot|x-x_0|$$
$$<K\cdot|a|\cdot\delta\leq K\cdot |a|\cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{K\cdot |a|}=\varepsilon$$
So, $f$ is continuous for $n\geq 2$ and $x_0$.

iv) It can be shown using a similar method to iii) that $f$ is continuous for $n\geq 2$ and $x_0<0$.

Thus, $f(x)=ax^n$ is continuous for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. $\square$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks very good from what I can see. Very rigorous and exact. There is absolutely nothing wrong with it.

---

However, let me give another example which is just as strict, but perhaps (in my completely subjective opinion), slightly easier to follow.

For case iii:

Let $M= \max_{x\in(x_0-1, x_0+1)}\left\{|a||x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}x_0 + \cdots + x_0^{n-1}|\right\}$.

Pick $$\delta = \min\left\{1, \frac{\epsilon}{M}\right\}.$$

Now, assuming that $|x-x_0|<\delta<1$, we know that $x\in(x_0-1, x_0+1)$. Therefore,

$$|a||x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}x_0 + \cdots + x_0^{n-1}| < \max_{x\in(x_0-1, x_0+1)}\left\{|a||x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}x_0 + \cdots + x_0^{n-1}|\right\} = M.$$

Now, we can simply see that

$$|f(x)-f(x_0)| = |a||x-x_0||x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}x_0 + \cdots + x_0^{n-1}|< M\cdot\delta <M\cdot\frac\epsilon M = \epsilon.$$

---

To me, the proof above is slightly easier to follow, as it in effect first limits itself to looking at $f$ on $(x_0-1, x_0+1)$ - as continuity really only cares for values close to $x_0$.

However, like I said, this proof is not *more correct* than yours, it's purely subjective opinion.

Comment: I have seen the use of putting $x$ in the interval of $(x_0-1,x_0+1)$ before, but I don't understand how it works. What exactly is happening when this is done, and why can it be done?

Comment: @drfrankie Well, what exactly is happening is exactly what is happening in my proof. Try re-checking all the steps of my proof. Is any of them unclear? If so, which one? I am happy to explain that particular step further.

Comment: re-read the proof, don't know how I didn't understand it the first time.

Comment: @drfrankie It's the nature of mathematics to be an egg of Columbus type thing. Once something is clear, it's "obvious". It's getting to the point where it's clear that's the hard part. So don't beat yourself up for it, but rather pat yourself on the back :)